# Why is this attribute based selector giving error in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
alert($("div#keylist ul li").filter("[display=block]").first().position().top);
```

I do have a div with id as keylist and there is an unordered list in it. I want .position().top of first visible element.

Comment: @Rajesh No, It doesn't. See https://api.jquery.com/filter/

Comment: [display=block] is not a selector. you have to pass filter a valid css selector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actualy `[display=block]` is not a right selector

use :visible selector instead

```
alert($("div#keylist ul li:visible").first().position().top);
```

I think this is what you need

```
alert($('ul > li').filter(function(){
  return $(this).css('display') == 'block';
}).first().text());
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/aqqf839n/)

Comment: are display=block and visibility=visible same thing?

Comment: @YogeshYadav No its not the same display show/hide the div to shown in the Dom and empty its place but with visibility the element place is still in its place but visible or not

Comment: I want the selector to select all li with display=block. How can i do that?

Comment: *"[display=block] is not a right selector"*. It **is** totally right selector. It's just doesn't do what OP's expects. Also *"yes with li:visible that mean display:block not mean visible for visibility"* is not correct. `:visible` has nothing to do with `display: block`. Non-block elements also can be *visible*.

Comment: @dfsq you are totally right in the second point but [display=block] its not a right selector [style="display:block"] may be the right one

Comment: `[display=block]` is okay. This is attribute selector, selects elements with attribute `display` equal to `block`. Nothing wrong with it. It's just won't select what OP wants.

Comment: @YogeshYadav I want the selector to select all li with display=block  and in your code you use .first()  you make me confused what you trying to do

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef I meant that first I will select all li with display=block and then choose the first out of that list.

Comment: @dfsq In what situations would I use "[display=block]"? And what if I want to select all li with custom attribute with a particular value? (like in "[custattr=val]")

Comment: @YogeshYadav Trying to select anything by CSS property is possible (see recent update of Mohamed-Yousef) but this is deadend. Not flexible enough.

Comment: @YogeshYadav with attribute you can use li[custattr=val]

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned inn the previous answers `[display=block]` is not a selector. But if you still insist on selecting `li` elements which has this css property you can go by class

Here are few way you can achieve the same

```
// Using Filter
alert("Using Filter " +$("div#keylist ul li").filter(".blockDec").first().position().top);
```

Since you already have parent as `div#keylist` you can use `find()` rather than using `filter()`

[Here](http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/difference-between-filter-and-find-in-jquery/) is difference between `filter & find`

Also you can take a look [Here](http://www.sitepoint.com/efficient-jquery-selectors/) & [Here](https://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/) to optimized the selector

```
//Using find .Here it will find all child element of ul
alert("Using Find " +$("div#keylist ul").find(".blockDec").first().position().top);

//Optimizing the jQuery selector 
alert("Optimized " +$("#keylist").find(".blockDec:first").position().top);
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/8ewhvh6n/4/)